# Get browser locale automatically

Tags: symfony, locale

I'm trying to internationalize my website using Symfony.
This is my routing.yml:

```
index:
    pattern: /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Index:index, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr
```

When the URL is just "/", "en" locale is set automatically, this is great but I want the browser locale.
For exemple, if I'm in France and I type "/", I want redirect to "/fr/", etc.

Can you help me?

Comment: @malcolm Not so simple for me :D, can you be more specific?

Comment: If you haven't read all the Symfony's documentation (at least about the related arguments) then is surely not simple understand what @malcolm wrote. PS: IMHO force the user redirect basing on browser language instead of allow a selection of the language is surely a bad approach

Comment: @gp_sflover Yeah I'll read all doc, this is a good idea.
Plenty of website redirect the user to his locale using http language accept in the request

Answer (score 3):

you can get client locale and set redirection in controller

```
$clientLocale = strtolower(str_split($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 2)[0]);
switch ($clientLocale) {
    case 'fr':
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fr_route'));
    break;
    default:
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('en_route'));
    break;
}
```

Comment: Where I put this code, I have plenty of controllers, do I need to do this on each controller?

Answer (score 1):

Based on b3da answer, I'll apply it only for the index route (as I think that is the main case when someone type your domain without params) and relying on my YML translations:

```
#routing.yml
index:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Pub:index


index2:
    path: /{_locale}
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Pub:index



#PubController.php
public function indexAction($_locale=null, Request $request) {
    if (!$_locale) {
        $browserLocale = strtolower(str_split($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 2)[0]);
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index2', ['_locale' => $browserLocale]));
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle::index.html.twig', []);
}
```

If the local browser is not translated on your app/Resources/translation YMLs then it will render the texts using your fallback locale (app/config/parameters.yml).